# Reporting framework for Java spring web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Am working on a java spring web application. I want to implement reporting features for it. the main feature i want to implement in reporting is that i should be able to select some parameters. depending on that the reports should be generated. Parameter selection mean: i select 2 dates and the report should be generated for the data within those 2 dates. this is just an example. can anyone suggest me on what i should be using?

Comment: I know and have heard jasper is good. i have tried a sample application from that. but in that i was just able to click on the button and reports used to export to either PDF or EXCEL. My question is can i do that depending on the parameters? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Taking off from your question in the comments section on using parameters in JasperReports:

> 4.1. Parameters
> Parameters are useful for passing data to the report engine that it can not find > in its data source or when data changes depending on different runtime > > conditions.
>
> We can also change portions or even the entire SQL query with parameters received > in the report filling operation.

The section 4.1 of [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jasper) should help you with creating a query statement with the parameters.